# Simple mistake in java constructor

Tags: java

I can not understand my mistake in this code, it will compile if I write `new Cosine();` but fails if I write `new Cosine(x);`

```
import java.lang.Object;
import java.lang.Math;

class Cosine {
    double Cosine (double x) {
    double result = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x));
    return result;
  }
}

public class test {
     public static void main (String[] args){
     double x = 90;
     new Cosine(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a very strange structure here. It's not normal to create a Cosine class to store the results of a cosine calculation, unless you are somehow wanting to create classes for different kinds of operations. If that's the case all the different ones should have the same calling mechanism: e.g. a 'calculate' method that returns a double, that is implemented differently for Sine, Cosine and Tangent classes.

Comment: Do you know what is constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't given `Cosine` a constructor that takes a `double`. Try this:

```
class Cosine {

    public final double result; //field holding the result

    //constructor
    public Cosine (double x){
     result = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x)); //compute the result
   }
}

public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        double x = 90;
        double cosX = new Cosine(x).result;
    }
}
```

Although this raises the question why a simple static method couldn't be used:

```
public static double getCosine(double x) {
    return Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x));
}

public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        double x = 90;
        double cosX = getCosine(x);
    }
}
```

This doesn't require the instantiation of a `Cosine` object for every computation.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have not declared a constructor that takes in a double. You can declare new Cosine() because there is the implicit no arg constructor. But in order to pass in a double you would have to explicitly create one.

```
public Cosine(double x){
  ...
}
```

However, if you just want to run the method that you have written to get the cosine you can declare a Cosine object then reference the method.

```
Cosine cos=new Cosine();
cos.cosine(4.2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double Cosine (double x){
```

should be

```
Cosine (double x){
```

because constructors don't have a return value.

Answer (score 1):

a java constructor would be

```
public Cosine(double x){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`double Cosine(double x)` is not a constructor. It's a method. Constructors don't have return types.

So use `Cosine(double x)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any constructor taking double as parameter

Answer (score 1):

You haven't created a constructor for `Cosine` -- so the compiler is supplying a default, no-args constructor.

This

```
double Cosine (double x){
double result = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x));
return result;
  }
```

is being parsed as a method declaration (I think).

Answer (score 0):

> double Cosine (double x) {
>       double result = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x));
>       return result;
>   }

This is not constructor. This is method declaration.
Here

> double Cosine(double x){}

is method declaration.
There are some rules for defining a constructor as follows:
1.It has the same name as the
class in which it resides and is syntactically similar to a method.
2.**They have no return type, not even void.**
3.The constructor
is automatically called immediately after the object is created, before the new operator completes.

As in the above question method

> Cousine(double x)

has return type **double**, it **breaks the 2nd rule**.

I ran the code on my machine resulted in an error:

> test.java:14: cannot find symbol
>   symbol : constructor Cosine(double)
>   location: class Cosine
>           new Cosine(x);
>   ^
>   1 error

It means that there is no parametrized constructor defined in program.

**Update**
Add constructor

```
Cosine(double x){
   ....
   .....
}
```